# Detect the order of clients connect to WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there a way to know that which client is the first, or the second,.. that connects to the WCF Service?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a415100f-c8cd-49af-9396-a8a249a5b5f5/how-to-find-out-the-details-of-the-client-connected-to-the-wcf-service?forum=wcf

Comment: @redaa that link no help bro - but thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it in your business logic. I.E. - request client to call some authentication method and calculate their index when doing so, and request auth token to be passed to every other method you have in service. In this context "first connected client" means client that first called authentication method.

Naive implementation where we calculate just index:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService {
  [OperationContract]
  int GetMyIndex();
  [OperationContract]
  void AnyOtherMethod(string foo, int clientIndex);
}

public class Service : IService {
  static int m_Counter;
  static object m_SyncRoot = new object();
  public int GetMyIndex() {
    lock (m_SyncRoot) {
      m_Counter++;
      return m_Counter;
    }
  }

  public void AnyOtherMethod(string foo, int clientIndex) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: That's no good because a client repeatedly calling **GetMyIndex()** will get a different value each time during the life of the client proxy, even if the service is **InstanceContextMode.PerSession**.